# How to integrate azure msi in chef inspec?

Tags: azure-devops, chef-infra, inspec

We are trying to use chef inspec in the azdo to validate the terraform provisioned resources but here looks like we have to keyin tenantid, secretid, clientid and subscription. Is there any way to we can use **azure msi** in chef inspec without parsing secret?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can pass values as a secret variables to your pipeline job. Then replace chef inspec azure authentication environment variables with these secrets.
2. If you don't want to pass variables, then save  Azure SPN credentials in Azure Key Vault and use AzureKeyVault@2 task in your pipeline to read and set chef inspec azure authentication environment variables.